# Value of self changes after pushViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, self

I'm using a UINavigationController and I want to reuse a UITableView. To that end, I've made the data sources for the table properties. Here are the files for the view.

WordList.h:

```
@interface WordList : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,   UISearchBarDelegate>{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *selfRef;
@property (assign) NSDictionary *wordList;
@property (assign) NSArray *indexList;
@property (assign) UINavigationController *useNC;


- (void)setNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)nc;
- (void)setSource:(NSString *)source;
- (void)dealloc;

@end
```

WordList.m:

```
@implementation WordList

@synthesize selfRef;
@synthesize wordList;
@synthesize indexList;
@synthesize useNC;

//static NSDictionary *wordList = nil;
//static NSArray *indexList = nil;
//static UINavigationController *useNC;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
  self.title = @"English -> ASL";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  if (!wordList){
    Database *db = [Database singleton];

    if (db) wordList = [db getWordList];

    indexList = [wordList allKeys];/*[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", 
                                    @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];*/

    [wordList retain];
    [indexList retain];
  }
}

- (void)setSource:(NSString *)source {
  Database *db = [Database singleton];

  NSLog(@"%@:setSource", self);

  if (db) wordList = [db runWordListQuery:source];

  NSLog(@"Word list: %@", wordList);

  indexList = [wordList allKeys];/*[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", 
                                  @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];*/

  NSLog(@"Index list: %@", indexList);

  [wordList retain];
  [indexList retain];
}  

- (void)setNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)nc {
  NSLog(@"%@:setNavigationController(%@)", self, nc);

  useNC = nc;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  NSLog(@"WordList:dealloc");

  if (wordList) [wordList release];
  if (indexList) [indexList release];

  [super dealloc];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  EntryViewer *ev = [[EntryViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"EntryViewer" bundle:nil];
  if (ev){
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO animated:YES];

    [ev setEntry:[[[wordList objectForKey:[indexList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ident]];

    if (useNC){
      [useNC pushViewController:ev animated:YES];
    }
    else {
      [APP_LISTNAV pushViewController:ev animated:YES];
    }

    [ev release];
  }
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return indexList;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [indexList objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  NSLog(@"%@:numberOfSectionInTableView(%u): %@", self, [indexList count], indexList);

  return [indexList count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
  NSInteger section = -1;

  section = [indexList indexOfObject:title];

  return section;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  // Return the number of rows in the section.

  return [[wordList objectForKey:[indexList objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *CellIdentifier = [[[wordList objectForKey:[indexList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = CellIdentifier;

  return cell;
}

@end
```

I'm still finding my feet in regards to Objective-C properties so I may be misusing them. The problem is that, even though the assignments in setSource: work, the table shows no data. Please see the NSLog() output below.

```
2011-10-17 10:58:22.387 ASL Dictionary[381:207] <WordList: 0x614f0b0> - WorldList:setSource
2011-10-17 10:58:22.394 ASL Dictionary[381:207] Word list: {
    H =     (
        "HOME (noun)"
    );
}
2011-10-17 10:58:22.395 ASL Dictionary[381:207] Index list: (
    H
)
2011-10-17 10:58:22.396 ASL Dictionary[381:207] <WordList: 0x614f0b0> - WorldList:setNavigationController(<UINavigationController: 0x573e780>)
2011-10-17 10:58:22.402 ASL Dictionary[381:207] <WordList: 0x57806f0> - numberOfSectionInTableView(0): (null)
```

It's clear why the table shows no data, the call to `numberOfSectionsInTable:` returns 0. What I want to know is why. I'm pretty certain, as you can see from the log, that it's because the value of `self` is different from the previous two calls. Why is this? The third call comes after the call to `pushViewController:`. Is that the reason? Am I approaching this wrong or have I missed something simple?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your number of sections is returning `nul`, which could be the problem.

Try hard-coding it to 1 (`return 1;`) also NSLog the value of `CellIdentifier` as you may be returning nothing there.

HTH

Comment: Sorry, I already knew that it was returning nil, I mentioned that in the question. I know why it's returning nil, it's because nothing's been set on the instance of WordList. You can see why from the console output, the instance being called changes from 0x614f0b0 to 0x57806f0. I was asking why the instance being used changes between calls.